# ClaimTransformation to update an integer value

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to create a custom policy to record the number of failed signin request for a user. After 5 failed signins in a row, the account needs to be disabled.

My approach was to use a B2C user attribute to record the number of signin failures, but I cannot find a way to increment the user attribute. How would I do this using custom policies?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achive is available out of box. 
Please use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management#manage-password-protection-settings to automatically lock account when wrong password is entered.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have disabled strong passwords for users. I have done this so we can have custom password complexity rules